# gzip a file quicker using Python?

Tags: python, performance, gzip

I am attempting to gzip a file using python faster as some of my files are as as small as 30 MB and as large as 4 GB.

Is there a more efficient way of creating a gzip file than the following? Is there a way to optimize the following so that if a file is small enough to be placed in memory it can simply just read the whole chunk of the file to be read rather than do it on a per line basis?

```
with open(j, 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open(j + ".gz", 'wb') as f_out:
        f_out.writelines(f_in)
```

Answer (score 4):

Copy the file in bigger chunks using the `shutil.copyfileobj()` function. In this example, I'm using 16MiB blocks which is pretty reasonable.

```
MEG = 2**20
with open(j, 'rb') as f_in:
    with gzip.open(j + ".gz", 'wb') as f_out:
        shutil.copyfileobj(f_in, f_out, length=16*MEG)
```

You may find that calling out to `gzip` is faster for large files, especially if you plan to zip multiple files in parallel.

Comment: +1 for copyfileobj. It is not clear that larger `length` leads to the better time performance (it may even slowdown the process). Unrelated: you could combine `with`-statements, to write it on a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading it line by line, you can read it at once.
Example:

```
import gzip
with open(j, 'rb') as f_in:
    content = f_in.read()
f = gzip.open(j + '.gz', 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

Comment: would f.write(file_content) work? to create a compressed file?

Comment: Sorry I misread your question. You can read the file at once into content and write it all together.

Comment: But if j is big, you may run out of memory. 4GB is quite a strain on the RAM.

Comment: this works better, what about reading chunks and writing to the gzip within the iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Find 2 almost identical methods for **reading** gzip files below:

- A.) to **load everything into memory** --> can be a bad choice for very big files (several GB), because you can run out of memory
- B.) Don't load everything into memory, **line by line** --> **good for BIG files**

adapted from
https://codebright.wordpress.com/2011/03/25/139/
and
https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2olhrf/fast_gzip_in_python/
http://pastebin.com/dcEJRs1i

> ```
> import sys
> if sys.version.startswith("3"):
>     import io
>     io_method = io.BytesIO
> else:
>     import cStringIO
>     io_method = cStringIO.StringIO
> ```

A.)

```
def yield_line_gz_file(fn):
    """
    :param fn: String (absolute path)
    :return: GeneratorFunction (yields String)
    """
    ph = subprocess.Popen(["gzcat", fn], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    fh = io_method(ph.communicate()[0])
    for line in fh:
        yield line
```

B.)

```
def yield_line_gz_file(fn):
    """
    :param fn: String (absolute path)
    :return: GeneratorFunction (yields String)
    """
    ph = subprocess.Popen(["gzcat", fn], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    for line in ph.stdout:
        yield line
```

Comment: Cool, do you have any timings? :)

Comment: @Roelant Nope, but I think version A was faster.